# store data to models from firebase in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to store data in array of model from firebasedatabase

my firebasedatabase response look like this:

```
 {-Ku3EYNaR_E5XVhAij2w: {customerAddress: Ram, customerMobileNumber: 921212121211, CustomerName: Ram, customerImageURL: }, -Ku3F6_0jro_5CI7FDsY: {customerAddress: Qweqweqwe, customerMobileNumber: 888888, CustomerName: Siva, customerImageURL: }}
```

and my model look like this

```
   class listOfUsers {
   String name = '';
    String phoneNumber = '';
    String address = '';
   listOfUsers(this.name,this.phoneNumber,this.address);
   }


 List<listOfUsers>userInformation_ = <listOfUsers>[];
 getusersinfo() async{
 FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();

 if (user != null) {
  _messagesRef
    .child(user.uid)
    .child('x')
    .onValue
    .listen((Event event) {
  print('value: ${event.snapshot.value}');
  var a = event.snapshot.value;

  for(var child in event.snapshot.value){
    print(child);
    }



   });
   }
   }

   getting error as 
   [VERBOSE-2:dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
    NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap' has no instance      getter 'iterator'.
   Receiver: _LinkedHashMap len:2
```

can any one help me to store data from firebase database to models in flutter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either write a serialization method and deserialization constructor manually that creates JSON from the class instance / takes the JSON and assigns the values to the instance fields

or you can use one of the code generation solutions to get that code generated automatically

- https://pub.dartlang.org/search?q=json_serializable
- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/built_value (provides immutable types)

Comment: if I am using JSON.decode(event.snapshot.value); then showing error as [VERBOSE-2:dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
 type '_InternalLinkedHashMap' is not a subtype of type 'String' of 'source' where
   _InternalLinkedHashMap is from dart:collection
   String is from dart:core

Comment: can u please give me the example  to bind data

Comment: If it's a `Map` (`_InternalLinkedHashMap` is the internal representation of a map), there is no need to decode it, it's already decoded. You can `encode` it, to get a JSON string that you can send using a HTTP request. It's a bit confusing that a  `Map` is often called JSON in Dart code, even when it actually isn't yet (before encoding it to a string).

Comment: if we know the key we can access, I had done in past but here it is run time firebase uniqueid so I am using for loop and trying to iterate but it is iteration is not available

Comment: You can get all the informations from a map. For example using `map.keys` like `map.keys.forEach((k) => print('$k: ${map[k]}'));` Not sure if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: response.forEach((Map map) => userInformation_.add(new listOfUsers(map["CustomerName"], map["customerMobileNumber"],map["customerAddress"], map["customerImageURL"])));                    error is like this type '(Map) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic, dynamic) => void' of 'f'

Comment: I think it is same error  for the first I am using functional programming it is saying no instance getter 'iterator' now it is saying no subtype '(dynamic, dynamic)' => void of 'f'

Comment: If you iterate over the map directly, then the callback needs 2 parameters as the error message shows, because then you get key and value. If you instead iterate over the keys as I explained in my previous comment, you get only the key value which you then can use (inside the callback) to get the value stored with the key. Just 2 different ways to achieve the same.